# Dictionary of Lists into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

`d = {"name: "name1", "key1" : ["A", "B"], "key2": ["C"]}`
and I want to create DataFrame with 1 row and columns `name`, `key1` and `key2` with values respectively  `name1`,`["A", "B"]` and `["C"]`

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([d])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create it with index orientation then transpose it.

```python
import pandas as pd

d = {"name": "name1", "key1" : ["A", "B"], "key2": ["C"]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').transpose()
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    name    key1 key2
0  name1  [A, B]  [C]
```

**Update:**

[Henry Ecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15497888/henry-ecker) posted a a simpler way using the `DataFrame.from_record()` function. This creates the same data frame structure as above.

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([d])
```